# Common Language Runtime (CLR) on Mac M1

Tags: database, azure, t-sql, clr

I'm Data Analyst student and using Macbook Pro M1.

At this time of my study we are using AdventureWorks2019 database.

Part of the exercise we have are not available for me because as far as I understand CLR isn't support on Azure-SQL-EDGE.

Solving this is really necessary for continue.

Any solutions?

Searched all over the net.

Comment: Use an environment that supports SQL Server. That *is* your solution.

Comment: What does "environment that supports SQL Sever" mean?
Sorry if i'm being noob.

Comment: An AMD64 Architecture environment, or an Azure Managed Instance. You can't run SQL Server on ARM architecture.

Comment: Like using virtual machine and run Windows on it or something?

there is not other way to bypass it?

Comment: You might be able to use a virtual host or translation layer, yes. Though you would likely have a much easier time by using supported hardware & software.

Comment: I’ve understand.
But buying new PC isn’t option for now :)

Comment: @tomerjo register new Account on MS Azure and create a new x64 VM for your studies. MS offers free accounts with $200 credit + 12 months of free access to some services.

Comment: Still Having a lot of problems.
I've powered Paralleles with Windows 11.
downloaded sql server 2022, and the installation fails.
tried ubuntu, fails.
Everything just fails.

Comment: Which is why you need to actually use supported hardware, @tomerjo .